# HTTP-CLASS-Redirecting traffic-F5

Tags: f5-big-ip, web-application-firewall

Can we redirect https traffic to a particular real server using http-class in F5? i.e whether http-class works with both http and https traffic.?

Answer (score 0):

An HTTP class can be used for HTTPS traffic as long as you add a client SSL profile to the virtual server to decrypt the SSL before processing the HTTP.

Aaron